# Why wont Micro USB Hub work with UVC Receiver?

Tags: usb, android, hub

I want to charge my phone and be able to receive wireless signal via a UVC Receiver. So I ordered a Micro USB Hub Adapter that supports OTG and charging. Well, I tested the hub adapter today, but the UVC receiver does not detect my transmitter when it's plugged in to the adapter.

This is the hub adapter i ordered: [Micro USB HUB Adaptor with Power, TUSITA 3-Port Charging OTG Host Cable Cord Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LTHBCNM)

And this is the UVC Receiver: [FPV Receiver, EACHINE ROTG01 UVC OTG 5.8G 150CH Full Channel FPV Receiver for Android Mobile Phone Tablet Smartphone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071VZYLYH)

When the UVC Receiver is plugged directly into the phone via the Micro USB port, the app I use to stream my camera feed reads "USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" and then I can select the USB Web Camera to stream the feed. However, I don't see that message when plugged in through the hub. The First Person View (FPV) app I am using is called [Go FPV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vertile.fpv3d&hl=en_US).

Should a Micro USB Hub Adapter be able to support a UVC Receiver ? If so, it is a bug inside the Go FPV app? Your thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: it is unclear what is the actual area of failure ... in the first part of your post you say that the transmitter is not being detected, but in the second part of your post you say that the receiver is not being detected .... which part is actually failing?

Comment: i should be more clear. I believe the receiver is not detected on my device. As a result, it is not able to detect the transmitter.

Comment: it is possible that your device is not a USB master when it is plugged into the USB hub ... plug a flash drive into the hub and see if it is detected by the phone

Comment: This question is off topic here as it is not about electronic design.  You might test the USB adapter with some other device like a keboard or mouse though.  But solving problems with products is not within the mission of this site.

Comment: ok thanks. it is possible to move this question to another stack exchange? btw the phone does work as a USB master with other devices like a mouse

Comment: Does the mouse work behind your "HUB Adaptor"? Or any keyboard? Or USB flash drive?

Comment: yes it works with other devices. I figured out why the receiver wasnt working. It draws 5 Volts, which it probably wasn't receiving from the hub.